# Entity Framework per-request context - how are errors handled?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have adopted a per-request context for my entities, mainly because most of my activity is fetching, although there is some updating.

With this approach its difficult to react to update issues. For instance I might need to do b) if a) fails inside a user control. The management of the per-user request is in my Global.asax.

Is the only way to revert to a per-transaction for these entities or is there another approach i could take?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it comes to actual database interactivity, yes transactions would be the idea scenario simply because it becomes an all or nothing scenario i.e. if something goes wrong, *everything* is rolled back.

However, if you are referring to the scenario whereby you would insert a record as a single transaction and you then do further processing later which depends on that record but fails, then in that scenario you would need to look at something like the [Command Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) - the jist of it is you would implement an undo mechanism.

Comment: Sounds like the command pattern is the one, i'll take a look.

Comment: @user1437135 There is also the option of re-using the same transaction object across multiple queries but I think this might complicate things futher...